# bulk api v2.0 Bad Request

Tags: apex, json, callout, bulk-api-v2

I am trying to make a simple call to create a bulk job, but I am getting 400 bad request errors. It works fine with the postman.

```
String objectName = 'Asset';
        String operation = 'update';     

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setEndpoint(URl.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v52.0/jobs/ingest');       
        request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json' );
        request.setHeader('Authorization' ,'Bearer '+userInfo.getSessionId() );//CR  
       
        String body = '{ '+                        
                        '"operation": "'+operation+'",'+ 
                        '"object": "'+objectName+
                      '}';
        
        request.setBody(body);
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse resp = h.send(request);
```

**Error:**
**CALLOUT_RESPONSE [100]|System.HttpResponse[Status=Bad Request, StatusCode=400]**

Comment: Your JSON is malformed. If you run your code in debug mode, it's easy to see how and where it's wrong.

Comment: I just resolved, noticed that missing closing quote for the body.